# I need help comparing data within a table in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table

| a1b1 | a1Eb1 | a1b2 | a1Eb2 | a2b1 | a2Eb1 | a2b2 | a2Eb2 | a3b1 | a3Eb1 | a3b2 | a3Eb2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 8 | 54 | 3 | 56 | 3 | 67 | 2 | 78 | 7 | 75 |
| 8 | 30 | 6 | 67 | 6 | 35 | 4 | 56 | 3 | 85 | 6 | 74 |
| 5 | 54 | 4 | 64 | 7 | 23 | 6 | 48 | 4 | 67 | 4 | 82 |
| 6 | 65 | 7 | 53 | 8 | 27 | 7 | 35 | 5 | 25 | 3 | 64 |
| 4 | 34 | 2 | 52 | 4 | 28 | 8 | 27 | 6 | 94 | 2 | 29 |

i want to compare the following data:

a1b1 vs a1b2;

then generate arrays containing

| a1b1 | a1b2 | minor a1b1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 20 |

| a1b2 | a1b1 | minor a1b2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 8 | 30 |

and so for each row of the table

and for each of the following comparisons

- a2b1 vs a2b2;
- a3b1 vs a3b2;

I have tried to do it with pandas in python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame ({'a1b1':[2,8,5,6,4],
                    'a1Eb1':[20,30,54,65,34],
                   'a1b2':[8,6,4,7,2],
                    'a1Eb2':[54,67,64,53,52],                   
                   'a2b1':[3,6,7,8,4],
                    'a2Eb1':[56,35,23,27,28],                   
                    'a2b2':[3,4,6,7,8],
                    'a2Eb2':[67,56,48,35,27],
                    'a3b1':[2,3,4,5,6],
                    'a3Eb1':[78,85,67,25,94],    
                   'a3b2':[7,6,4,3,2],
                   'a3Eb3':[75,74,82,64,29],
                   })
```

but i don't know how to go on.

Output expected

To the first line a1b1<a1b2 then print the following

```
df1=pd.DataFrame{'a1b1':[2],
                 'a1b2':[8], 
                'a1Eb1':[20]}
```

This can be, a DataFrame, a list or any data structure

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "generate vectors"? I'm not very up on linear algebra.

Comment: I meant an array

Comment: can you post the expected output for that sample

Comment: So if `a1b1` is smaller than `a1b2`, you want the `a1Eb1` to be in the new list instead of `a1Eb2` ?

Comment: Oh, I see. So then, what have you actually tried? Have you taken a Pandas tutorial? Do you know how to compare columns? Maybe you could use `.mask()` or `.where()`? Secondly, it's not clear what the full output should be for that data. Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Start with the [tour]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only specific columns of your dataframe you can use the following syntax with `[[` and `]]` after the name of the dataframe (`df`), and in between you just add the names of the columns you want to see. It can be 2,
3 or even all of the columns of the dataframes, as long as you separate their names with a comma and put them between quotes.

```
df[['a1b1','a1b2']] # to display two columns
df[['a2b1','a2b2']]
df[['a3b1','a3b2']]
```

to display 3 columns, it could for example be :

```
df[['a3b1','a3b2','a3b1']]
```

and so on.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the two sets of brackets mean different things. The outer ones are for indexing and the inner ones make a list.